# Permission for internal users to manage external users

Tags: customer-portal, permissions, user-management

I am trying to allow people in support to provision new customer portal users (We haven't switched to communities yet).  When I go to the contact record I see the 'Manage External User' button, but other users cannot see this.

[image]

http://na6.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_manage_users.htm

I have tried the 'Manage External Users'  and the 'edit self service users' permissions, as the above link suggests, but this still doesn't make the button appear.  What do I need to do (preferably in a permission set) to allow other internal users to manage external users for the customer portal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel like an idiot.  The 'Manage External Users', and the 'Edit Self Service Users' are the correct permissions, it just happened that the layout for a particular group of users did not have the button on their layout.  Glad it a was stupid silly fix, but definitely feel stupid.  thanks all

Comment: It happens to the best of us all the time. I'll give the points anyway for coming back and letting us know what's going on. Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Thank you.  Still embarrassed, but thanks  Haha